# Why methods in helper file are not aceessible from the controller in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.1

There is a method `has_edit_right?` defined in customers_helper.rb file. The method needs to be accessed by both the controller and its view. The rspec returns NoMethodError:

```
  1) CustomersController GET customer page 'edit' should be successful if current user is the owner of the customer
     Failure/Error: post 'edit', :id => customer.id, :customer => {:name => "name changed"}
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `has_edit_right?' for #<CustomersController:0x3df6980>
     # ./app/controllers/customers_controller.rb:40:in `edit'
     # ./spec/controllers/customers_controller_spec.rb:87:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Any thoughts about the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helpers are for views, that's their point. They aren't supposed to be available in the controller, they're specifically for distilling out reusable view logic. If you need a method available to both the controller and its views, define a `protected` method in the controller and provide it to the view via `helper_method`.

In this example, the method `has_edit_right?` defined in the controller will also be available to the views.

```
# app/controllers/posts_controller.rb

class PostsController < ApplicationController

  helper_method :has_edit_right?

  # ...

  def edit
    raise "Access Denied" unless has_edit_right?
    # ...
  end

  protected

  def has_edit_right?
    current_user.admin?
  end
end
```

---

```
# app/views/posts/show.html.erb

<% if has_edit_right? %>
  <%= link_to "Edit Post", edit_post_path(@post) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The method has_edit_right? needs to be accessed by both view and controller.

Comment: Then make it a method of your controller, or of `ApplicaitonController`, and provide it to your views via `helper_method :has_edit_right?`

Comment: See update, I was mistaken: Making a method of the controller is done via `helper_method`, not `helper`.

Comment: Another post suggests include CustomersHelper in controller to call the methods in helper file. It seems working.

Comment: For helper :has_edit_right?, if there is another method in helper called in has_edit_right?, do I need to list it in controller as well? Also do I need to include the arg for has_edit_rights in helper :has_edit_right?  ?

Comment: If your methods are being called from the controller, *they aren't helpers*. You need to put them all into the controller and make them accessable via `helper_method`. The methods, and any methods they call, must be defined in the controller. You do not need to include any arguments in the `helper_method` directive, only the method name.

Comment: It is working by putting those methods in customers controller and make them available to view with helper_method in controller. However do you think it is going to be OK with include CusotmersHelper in customers controller? It seems that the controller knows how to call methods in its view helper, even though the best place for those view helper methods may be in controller itself.